# Use a custom icon for displaying (gender) in plotly's library in python

Tags: python, plotly, visualization, plotly-dash

I was wondering if there's a way to have a custom icon for plotly's pie chart instead of the usual pie division

As of now I'm displaying the gender information using a pie chart which looks as below:

[image: the pie chart]

and im looking for something like this :

[image: the result waht i want]

this is the pie chart code

```
fig = px.pie(df5, values='count', names='gender')
fig.show()
```

and this is the gender df

| gender | count |
| --- | --- |
| Female | 666 |
| male | 1889 |

‎

Comment: No, there is not something like that. This can be done by photoshop or illustrator.

Comment: Read also about how to create an infographic.

Answer (score 2):

Your desired graphic is nice, but it's far too specific to exist natively in plotly. As @Hamzah mentioned, if you only need one chart, you would probably save time by manually creating the image yourself.

However, if for some reason you really want to use plotly (or you need to scale up the number of charts), I'll lay out the general idea. Hopefully someone else will find this useful in the future as well.

The first thing to do is get an image with a dark background where the man and woman are transparent (I used the wizard tool in preview to crop them out of the original image):

[image]

You can add this image to an empty plot at specific x and y coordinates (see [here](https://plotly.com/python/images/)), and then keep track of the left, right, top, and bottom x- and y-axis coordinates of the man and woman figures themselves. For convenience, I placed the image such that it spans from (0,0) to (3,1) in plotly figure coordinates.

Then I used plotly shapes (see [here](https://plotly.com/python/shapes/#rectangles-positioned-relative-to-the-axis-data)) to add blue rectangles with heights corresponding to the gender values in your `df5`, and placed these rectangles below the layer of the image so that it shows through the transparent man and woman. Then I added used plotly annotations to add text below the man and woman. Here is the result:

[image]

I want to stress that this is a very hacky solution and not really how plotly is intended to be used and there is a some hard-coding involved in determining the top, bottom, left, and right coordinates where the man and woman images start and end in this picture – but I could see this having a use case if someone needed to generate a large number of images or html files with the same logos with fill heights corresponding to percentages.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from PIL import Image

df5 = pd.DataFrame({
    "gender": ["Female","male"],
    "count": [666, 1889]
})

logo_height = 1
df5["height"] = logo_height * df5["count"] / df5["count"].sum()

fig = go.Figure()

man_woman_transparent_logo = Image.open("man_woman_transparent_logo.png")

fig.add_layout_image(
    dict(
        source=man_woman_transparent_logo,
        xref="x",
        yref="y",
        x=0,
        y=1,
        sizex=3,
        sizey=1,
        sizing="stretch",
        opacity=1,
        layer="below")
)

image_top = 0.86
image_bottom = 0.14
image_height = image_top-image_bottom
man_image_left = 0.3
man_image_right = 1.14
woman_image_left = 1.76
woman_image_right = 2.72

female_height_ratio = df5.loc[df5['gender'] == 'Female', ['height']].values[0][0]
male_height_ratio = df5.loc[df5['gender'] == 'male', ['height']].values[0][0]

## add blue fill for man
fig.add_shape(type="rect",
    x0=man_image_left, y0=image_bottom, 
    x1=man_image_right, y1=image_bottom + image_height*male_height_ratio,
    line=dict(width=0),
    fillcolor="LightSkyBlue",
    layer="below"
)

## add blue fill for woman
fig.add_shape(type="rect",
    x0=woman_image_left, y0=image_bottom, 
    x1=woman_image_right, y1=image_bottom + image_height*female_height_ratio,
    line=dict(width=0),
    fillcolor="LightSkyBlue",
    layer="below"
)

## add text for man
fig.add_annotation(
    text=f"{male_height_ratio*100:,.2f}% Male",
    font=dict(color="white", size=20),
    xref="x", yref="y",
    x=(man_image_left+man_image_right)/2, 
    y=image_bottom-0.05, 
    showarrow=False
)

## add text for woman
fig.add_annotation(
    text=f"{female_height_ratio*100:,.2f}% Female",
    font=dict(color="white", size=20),
    xref="x", yref="y",
    x=(woman_image_left+woman_image_right)/2, 
    y=image_bottom-0.05, 
    showarrow=False
)

fig.update_layout(
    xaxis=dict(showgrid=False, range=[0,3]),
    yaxis=dict(showgrid=False, range=[0,1]),
)
fig.update_xaxes(visible=False)
fig.update_yaxes(visible=False)
fig.show()
```